# How to print alt codes from data segment on assembly?

Tags: assembly

I want to make a maze map and I want the characters that make the maze to be the alt code of 219 - █ . When i try to put the sign on emu8086 it shows a question mark.

I thought about building the map on the data segment because its not small and on the data segment I can just design the map by a string but it just shows question marks instead of the character I want it to be.
how can I print them from data like so?, if i cant then can you suggest another way?

Comment: This may be a problem regarding the charset of the editor and the encoding/charset of the output system. I'm not familiar with emu8086, but it should be documented. If you define a byte of value 219 what symbols gets printed in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ASCII numeric codes instead of the chars themselves :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

chars  db  1,2,219,220,223,'$'   ;◄■■ CHARS NON VISIBLE IN EMU.

.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ah, 9
  lea  dx, chars
  int  21h          ;◄■■ DISPLAY SPECIAL CHARS.

  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h
```

A more complicated solution is to use a simple char and replace it at runtime by the special char :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

maze  db  '----------',13,10    ;◄■■ SIMPLE CHARS.
      db  '-        -',13,10
      db  '----------$'

.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  lea  si, maze  
display:  
  mov  dl, [si]
  cmp  dl, '$'  ;◄■■ CHECK END OF STRING.
  je   finale        
  cmp  dl, '-'  ;◄■■ IF THIS IS THE CHAR TO REPLACE
  jne  continue
  mov  dl, 219  ;◄■■ REPLACE SIMPLE CHAR WITH SPECIAL CHAR.
continue:
  mov  ah, 2
  int  21h      ;◄■■ DISPLAY CHAR IN DL.
  inc  si       ;◄■■ NEXT CHAR IN STRING.
  jmp  display

finale:  

  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h
```